# Как создать webm видео файл из нескольких буферов изображений RGB?

Tags: c++, видео, .webm, libvpx

Я задал аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911857/how-to-encode-few-rgb-image-buffers-to-webm-video) на англоязычном SO - подсказали в общем, что для этого нужно перевести RGB буфер в YV12 чтобы получить три буфера компонент Y, U, V, а затем воспользоваться "какой-то функцией из `vpx_codec_enc_*`". Только что-то я не нашёл ни одной функции в libvpv, принимающей эти три плана. Да и вообще не понятно какие ещё данные нужны кодеку и как их инициализировать.

Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с VP8/VP9 кодеками при помощи libvpx, и как получить webm видео на выходе? Не обязательно код - мне хотя бы понять какие структуры инициализировать и какие функции в каком порядке вызывать.

*PS: такое ощущение, что официальная документация рассчитана на экспертов по видео... я что-то не могу по ней понять как вообще работает кодек и что ему надо.*

Comment: А ffmpeg вы не пробовали использовать, по нему может быть больше документации и примеров.

Comment: @Unick, библиотека ffpmeg много весит и с ней тоже надо разбираться. Использовать бинарники ffmpeg не вариант, так как у меня исходный материал не в файлах - он формируется в памяти (вебка, экран), а конвертеры ffmpeg читают файлы для конвертации. Надо сделать свою низкоуровневую реализацию, но для этого мне бы понимать как это всё работает, что ест кодек... а код то я напишу сам.

Comment: На первый взгляд у libvpx достаточно примеров. Например https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/master/examples/simple_encoder.c там есть метод encode_frame, наверное он делат что вам нужно. Вроде и тип энкодера можно задать, функция get_vpx_encoder_by_name.